# «Увидеть себя в лицо»

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, местоимения

Поясните, пожалуйста, содержит ли ошибку предложение "Если бы студенты позволили увидеть себя в лицо"? Можно ли "увидеть в лицо"?
И корректно ли использование местоимения "себя", почему не "их"?
Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Есть некоторые формы, описывающие прикосновение или иное физическое воздействие на **своё** лицо (*Она давала целовать себя в лицо*; *Ткнул себя в лицо кулаком*). Однако глагол *увидеть* не допускает подобного согласования, и вопросы *во что*? или *куда?* в примере — «*увидеть себя в лицо*» — невозможны.

https://wordsonline.ru/combinations/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Тут в лицо имеется в виду в анфас. Увидеть в профиль, увидеть в анфас итп.

Comment: @user190920 Дайте ссылку, если источник и контекст известны. Автор вопроса не сообщил. Вообще **в анфас** возник из  **анфас** по типу формы **в профиль**, где предлог не лишний.